# Google sheet Duplicatea specific sheet from a specific sheet and specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wish to create a duplicate sheet, using the sheet named `Template` after a form has been submitted, "Form responses 1"= "Yes" of if easier someone enters "Yes" from a drop down sheet  from a sheet named `Start` and a duplicate of `Template` is created, with the name from that cell. I Have attempted using the code below  but would appreciate simple instructions.

```
function CreateNewTimesheet() 
{    
    // The code below makes a duplicate of the active sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();

    // The code below will rename the active sheet to Month End date based on cell O3
    var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("O3").getValue();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

I have written few code lines, may be this will help you.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //get template sheet
  var templateSheet  =ss.getSheetByName('Template').activate();
  //make a copy of template sheet
  var copySheet = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  //CHange new sheet nane
  var newSheetName = ss.getRange('Form Resposes 1!A1').getValue();
  copySheet.setName(newSheetName );
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I understand my question wasn't clear. I was hoping for the duplicate of a sheet would be triggered by a cell being filled in and that  Cell would become the 'NEW_SHEET_NAME'.   EG 'Form Resposes 1'A1="JEREMY_DUPLICATE", Which would trigger the function to Duplicate the sheet getSheetByName( 'Template') and rename it setName('JEREMY_DUPLICATE') but from that cell. 

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you can not trigger from cell edit to insert a new sheet. However you can trigger it on form submit. I have updated the code how to get the sheet name from a cell.